# Updating a single field on a record without manually typing in Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, firebase, eloquent, laravel-8

Is there any way to update a single field on a record without manually typing? I want to update a certain field by just pressing submit in Laravel 8.

I can display my data and I want to change the status from pending to approved or rejected after clicking one of the buttons.

[image]

my blade

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Requested By</th>
        <th>Amount in Words</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Reason</th>
        <th>Payable To</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Approve</th>
        <th>Reject</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    @foreach ($payment as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->amount_in_words }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->amount_in_figures }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->reason }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->payee }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->department_head }}</td>
        <td>
            <form method="PUT" action="{{route('payments.update', $item->id)}}" >
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                @method('PUT')
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" >Approve</button>
            
        </form>
        <td>
            
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Reject</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

My function in my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, Payment $item->id)
{
    $request->validate([
        DB::table('post')
        ->where('id', $item->id)
        ->update(['status' => "approved"]);
    ]);
   
    $payment->update($request->all());
    $payment->save();    
        return redirect()->route('home')
            ->with('success', 'payment updated successfully');
    }
```

I have tried this, but it not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to update data without manually typing it

change your code from this

```
public function update(Request $request, Payment $item->id)
{
    $request->validate([
        DB::table('post')
        ->where('id', $item->id)
        ->update(['status' => "approved"]);
    ]);
   
    $payment->update($request->all());
    $payment->save();    
        return redirect()->route('home')
            ->with('success', 'payment updated successfully');
    }
```

To this

```
public function update(Request $request, Payment $item->id)
{
    $request->validate([
        DB::table('post')
        ->where('id', $item->id)
        ->update(['status' => "approved"]);
    ]);
   
    $payment->update({
    'status' => 'approved',
    });
    $payment->save();    
        return redirect()->route('home')
            ->with('success', 'payment updated successfully');
    }
```